# What is the minimum sample size to get reliable results in haplotype and nucleotide estimations?

Tags: biodiversity

Different software have different methods for estimating diversity and each method will have assumptions about the quantity of
data required to produce a reliable result. I am estimating the haplotype and nucleotide diversity by DnaSP6 program of Sanger sequences. I would like what is the minimum sample size requires to get reliable results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information regarding what methods you are trying to use? Can you indicate the specific feature of DnaSP6 you are trying to use? This program implements many different analyses, each of which likely has different requirements. What are your input data? Are they just reads or have you done any postprocessing? How many loci? How many individuals, 10, 100, 1000?

Comment: I am trying to estimate haplotype and nucleotide diversity using gene flow . My input data are fasta files from sanger sequences, they code an unique protein. I have in some cases for some groups 2 or 3 individuals and I though that It could not be enought

Comment: "in some cases for some groups" what cases, what groups? are these population groups, groups that are the same protein, regions of the gene?

Comment: I have 13 groups defined of the total dataset, all of them of the same protein. 2 of these 13 groups have a sample size of 3 individuals each of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still a little unclear on what the analysis looks like, but I'm going to assume for the sake of this answer that it's a single locus sequenced across multiple populations, with some number of individuals per population, and that **the concern is that some of these populations are represented by only a few individuals**. I'm also going to assume that the individuals are diploid, so you in fact have a little more data than it appears.

All the same, [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3375404/) indicates that **n<5 individuals in a population leads to quite noisy estimates of $\pi$ and $h$** (section "The effect of sample size on haplotype and nucleotide diversities"). This is of course specific to a certain ~500bp region that they collected sequences for. That doesn't mean that you can't compute these metrics, only that they may not be very reliable.

For reference, the early Neanderthal genome papers compute some measures based on only the two copies present in their diploid genomes- of course, they are assisted by a large amount of modern human data for making comparisons. If you have supporting data from other populations, you may still be able to say something about the populations with few individuals. But you will likely have to use measures other than $\pi$ and $h$ to do so.

Some other tools that you might use to "borrow" information from other individuals outside those groups are ordination analyses such as [PCA](https://faculty.washington.edu/tathornt/SISG2015/lectures/assoc2015session05.pdf), or clustering tools like [STRUCTURE](https://web.stanford.edu/group/pritchardlab/structure.html). One way of thinking about how this works is that you can "embed" your populations with few individuals in the population structure of your overall dataset. This allows you to still learn from those populations even if the number of individuals is small. The Neanderthal papers implement versions of this, but with much more elaborate statistical frameworks, for a whole genome rather than just a single gene.

I'm not sure if DnaSP can carry out these analyses, but there are a lot of tools that do similar things, one tutorial [here](https://popgen.nescent.org/StartSNP.html). Of course looking at the [DnaSP manual](http://www.ub.edu/dnasp/DnaSP6_Documentation_6.12.pdf) is probably a good idea to see what you can do with your current tool.

Depending on your goals it may also be interesting to compute F-statistics across your populations, this is done by most population genetics tool suites. I used [GenePop](https://genepop.curtin.edu.au/) many years ago to do this, it appears to still work, though I am sure there are better alternatives now.

An important note is that most of these measures are purely descriptive, not inferential. Low sample size makes descriptive statistics noisy, but doesn't invalidate them. Inferential statistics are a bit more dangerous.

Comment: Thanks you Maximilian, my sequences are haploid and the other assumtions are correct.  I checked one article that use a sample size with n<3 for π and h (Host abundance and identity determine the epidemiology and evolution of a generalist plant virus in a wild ecosystem). However I would like to know what other measures than π and h  you mean to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: see edit with more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot Maiximilian for your properly answer. I will take consideration of your suggestions. Thanks